# Casting int array to object array

Tags: c#-4.0

Why is this legal,

```
string[] arr = new string[5];
Object[] arr2 = arr;
```

But this is a compile-time error,

```
int[] arr = new int[5];
Object[] arr2 = arr;
```

Aren't int and string both derived from Object? Is it a ValueType thing? If so, why is it this way?

Comment: I believe the answer is that a String is not a primitive type, whereas an int is a primitive type.

Comment: Value type is the correct word I believe.. doing this with Int32 still yields compile error.

Comment: Erm... I don't think Int32 is any different? Isn't "int" and "float" just the C# keyword, but Int32 and Int64 the "CLR" erm -- identifier -- for them? :)

Comment: But yeah, you may be right on the name part. I know that int, float, char, etc. are primitives, but value vs. reference type is more relevant to the discussion.

Comment: @aikeru Oops, sorry I was thinking Int32 wasn't primitive. So enum, decimal, and struct are the only value types that are not primitive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The C# language only provides covariance for arrays of reference types.  This is documented [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664572%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> For any two reference-types A and B, if an implicit reference conversion (Section 6.1.4) or explicit reference conversion (Section 6.2.3) exists from A to B, then the same reference conversion also exists from the array type A[R] to the array type B[R], where R is any given rank-specifier (but the same for both array types). This relationship is known as array covariance.

In your second example, you're using an array of `System.Int32` types, which are not reference types, so the array covariance support does not apply.  Reference types are, at their core, all storing an array of references, where the references are all an identical size.  Value types can be any size, so there is no guarantee that the array elements would be the same size, which prevents this from working properly.

Answer (score 4):

This is called [unsafe array covariance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/17/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-two-array-covariance.aspx).

It only works for arrays of reference types.

Arrays of value types are a physically different size, so this cannot work.